# adding criteria to an existing equation

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have this existing equation with two criteria

```
=SUMPRODUCT((kshc2013D=A6)*(kshc2013A=1))
```

what I want to achieve is if I add a third criteria wherein it will only count month `January` and `April` to a specified named range (`kshc2013B`)

I used

```
=SUMPRODUCT((kshc2013D=A6)*(kshc2013A=1)*(kshc2013B="April"))
```

which successfully count all under April but how to add another month to the equation is giving me error or zero results if I make

```
(kshc2013B="April";"January"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite clear if you want to include "January AND April" or "January OR April". There is a difference.

Take your pick

condition must be January AND April

```
=SUMPRODUCT((kshc2013D=A6)*(kshc2013A=1)*(kshc2013B="January")*(kshc2013B="April"))
```

condition can be January OR April

```
=SUMPRODUCT((kshc2013D=A6)*(kshc2013A=1)*((kshc2013B="January")+(kshc2013B="April")))
```

Comment: I need condition must be January AND April and =SUMPRODUCT((kshc2013D=A6)*(kshc2013A=1)*(kshc2013B="January")*(kshc2013B="April")) gave me zero value result

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT((kshc2013D=A6)*(kshc2013A=1)*((kshc2013B="January")+(kshc2013B="April"))) worked for me using my condition